# how to display images from symfony app to an angular 4?

Tags: php, angular, symfony, file-upload

i store the image with post request to symfony and it stores it in :
C:\xampp\htdocs\fileUploader/web/uploads/images/34414f8a9b2bfd430555e4ad6d4007ed.jpeg

and when i try to get it to display it i get this error !

**Not allowed to load local resource:** file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/fileUploader/web/uploads/images/34414f8a9b2bfd430555e4ad6d4007ed.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your images are in web folder, which is publicly available, so your images would be: `http://yourlocaldomain.com/uploads/images/34414f8a9b2bfd430555e4ad6d4007ed.jpeg`

Comment: @brahimbelkhiria happy to help :)